# У z-index есть предел?

Tags: html

Редактирую сайт и наткнулся на

```
 z-index: 9999;
```

у этого свойства вообще есть пределы и может ли оно быть отрицательным?

Comment: Теоретических пределов нет, практические пределы плюс-минус два миллиарда

Comment: Есть,  выше родителя не будет

Comment: По идее как и числа int от -2147483648 до 2147483647

Comment: @MaximLensky выше родителя тоже бывает, если уметь манипулировать позиционированием https://jsfiddle.net/u6xfk0qs/

Comment: @andreymal в этом случае да...есть такое когда не бывает

Comment: @andreymal. покажите в этом случае : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085646/Как-сделать-z-index-у-вложенного-элемента-больше-чем-у-родителя/1085832#1085832

Comment: @MaximLensky частные случаи позиционирования никак не влияют на синтаксически допустимый диапазон z-index, который согласно спецификации никак не ограничен

Comment: @andreymal а я про это говорил

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> у этого свойства вообще есть пределы?

Нет

> может ли оно быть отрицательным?

Да

---

*При равном значении z-index, на переднем плане находится тот элемент, который в коде HTML описан ниже.*

Comment: Совет: никогда не используйте большие значения, запутаетесь. Успехов!

Comment: Почему никогда? А если надо явно чтобы элемент перекрывал все содержимое сайта? Например разворачивающееся меня для мобильной версии. Проще же написать значение 9999 и в дальнейшем не заморачиваться? Или нет?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, из моего опыта нет, не проще. Проще, это: `1,2,3,4,5` и т.д. И `10,20,30` для каких-то специальных задач. Вот этого вполне хватает и никогда не запутаетесь. А `99999999999999` - зачем? Чтобы перекрыть `1`? Это просто добрый совет, а там каждый решает сам.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/minimum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index - говорят, если сравниваются два элемента с индексом от `2^31` и выше, он перестает на что-то влиять.